# Topbar not displaying responsive menu - foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am currently working with [foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com) and ultimately trying to make my page mobile friendly. I have a top navigation bar that I have created for the page following some of the basic structures. The navigation bar has problems being responsive. It does not display a menu at a all when I resize smaller the screen. How can I get the navigation bar to be responsive?

HTML:

```
<nav class="tab-bar show-for-small">
<a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
<span>Title</span>
</a>
</nav>

<nav class="top-bar docs-bar hide-for-small" data-topbar>
<ul class="title-area">
<li class="name">
<h1>
<a href="#">Title</a>
</h1>
</li>
</ul>
<section class="top-bar-section">
<ul class="right">
<li class="divider"></li>
 <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
    <a class="" href="#">Test</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
    <a href="#">SubTest</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
    <a class="" href="#">Test2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
    <a href="#">SubTest2</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
<li class="divider"></li>
 <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
    <a class="" href="#">Test3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
    <a href="#">SubTest3</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
</section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given it the class `.hide-for-small` for the main one which holds all of the dropdowns.

Then the one that is viewable by mobile, you have no data inside of it.

Add the `<a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
<span>Title</span>
</a>` to the other nav.

Refer to [this page here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) to get a proper responsive topbar.